# migrationg a hash function with 32 bit unsigned integers from c++/Qt to java

Tags: java, c++, qt

I have this function in C++/Qt:

```
quint32 updateHash(quint32 value, quint32 hash)
{
    return = hash ^ ((hash << 5) + (hash >> 2) + value);

}
```

I want to rewrite this exact behavior in Java.

First try:

```
private int updateHash(int value, int hash)
{
    return hash ^ ((hash << 5) + (hash >> 2) + value);
}
```

The method will be called several times consecutively.

The Java version gives the same results, as long as the resulting hash is below 2^16-1, so I think the problem is the unsinged integer type in C++, and the signed integer type in Java.

I have tried to use `Integer`, `long`, and `Long` in Java, but I don't get the right results.

How can I "mimic" unsigned int behavior in Java in bitwise operations?

Edit: As Requested, the expected output:
Left: Input value, right: calculated hash

First Hash is "0", after that the calculated hash is the input hash for the next result.

Expected Output with C++

```
87=>87
97=>2817
121=>92248
112=>2887134
111=>94417528
105=>2967391871
110=>4174335378
116=>2698169226
65=>3797741545
99=>1718212244
116=>2159844877
105=>3078518657
118=>2865822199
101=>771982389
```

Output with Java

```
87=>87
97=>2817
121=>92248
112=>2887134
111=>94417528
105=>2967391871
110=>3100593554
116=>2966604682
65=>3059544041
99=>258594452
116=>4269579789
105=>827225985
118=>124582391
101=>3893789749
```

It's going bad on the "110" input.

Edit2: @dasblinkenlight 's answer brought the correct thought to my mind, I will copy the comment I gave him here:

> However, using an int in java did not yield the same results as using
>   the C++ code.
>
> But your comment gave me the right hint for what I had
>   to look. In C++, the bitshift operators `<<` and `>>` work logical, in
>   Java these operators work arithmetic. So right-shifting will shift in
>   a "1" if the integer was negative, and a zero if the integer was
>   positive.
>
> Java has a special right-shift operator that works logical
>   (= always shifting in a "0"), that is `>>>`. Using that operator gives
>   me the correct results. Thanks!

Comment: Please give an input, an expected output and the actual output (preferably in hexidecimal).

Comment: I added the output to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mimic `unsigned int` in Java without using `long`: the only unsigned type in the language is `char`, but it has only 16 bits.

Good news is that as far as hash code is concerned, it absolutely does not matter that the number is signed / unsigned. Your verbatim translation will produce hash codes of the same quality as the QT original, so using them in hash containers will give you the same results.

You could extend the range in which the results between Java and QT would match to 31 bits by using `long` inside the method, i.e.

```
// The caller will be passing int for value and hash
private int updateHash(long value, long hash) {
    return (int)(hash ^ ((hash << 5) + (hash >> 2) + value));
}
```

but this would do more computation with no real advantages.

Comment: However, using an int in java did not yield the same results as using the C## code.

But your comment gaver me the right hint for what I had to look.

In C++, the bitshift operators "<<" and ">>" work logical, in Java these operators work arithmetic. So right-shifting will shift in a "1" if the integer was negative, and a zero if the integer was positive. Java has a special right-shift operator that works logical (= always shifting in a "0"), that is ">>>".  Using that operator gives me the correct results.  
Thanks!
(Sorry, I am not able to format this comment...)